# git checkout -- <files> doesn't discard changes?

Tags: macos, git, git-checkout

I have changes in my working directory that I'm trying to discard (reset to the current indexed version of the files), however, `git checkout -- <file>` will not discard the changes.
I've attempted to manually remove the files (`rm -r files`) then run `git checkout -- .`, which displays the files as modified again.

```
$ git checkout -- .
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   files/Hulk.png
#   modified:   files/Hulk_2.png
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Running `git diff` shows the files are modified...

```
diff --git a/files/Hulk.png b/files/Hulk.png
index 1c256cb..1d37fe0 100644
Binary files a/files/Hulk.png and b/files/Hulk.png differ
diff --git a/files/Hulk_2.png b/files/Hulk_2.png
index 1c256cb..0717199 100644
Binary files a/files/Hulk_2.png and b/files/Hulk_2.png differ
```

NOTE: Some people have said to run `git checkout .`, however this will achieve the same result as `git checkout -- .`. The `--` is just a notation used in the git checkout command to differentiate treeish/commit points from files/paths.

OS: OSX 10.6
Git: 1.7.10.2

Comment: Does `git reset --hard` work?

Comment: @vergenzt, no... doesn't work. I discovered the problem. I'm working with a repo that appears to have multiple files with the same names and different cases. Since I'm on an OSX workstation, which is case-insensitive, the files appeared to change, but not really. That's why I can't reset them nor can I commit the "change". I have to actually rename the files on a case sensitive OS and commit the result.

Comment: If you've come up with an answer, please add that answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @swatkins I haven't yet, I'm still working on it.

Comment: Sweet! Good luck getting that completed!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The cause for this was due to multiple files with the same name but different cases. In OSX, which is case-insensitive, doesn't like multiple files with the same name but different cases. It views them as the same file.
To fix this, I ran `git mv` (or just `mv`) to a temporary filename, added the temp files, which allowed git to remove the old/incorrectly named versions, then a second commit to name them back.
This could also be corrected on a filesystem which allows different files with the same name to be different cases.

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me get past an extremely frustrating bug in CocoaPods

Answer (score 9):

Did you try

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

or

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Comment: Why would one try that?

Comment: I use Git on Windows via Cygwin.  We have some crazy security policies that magically change permissions on files during Git actions.  (Others on Cygwin mailing list have noticed this.)  Git detects these file mode changes, but `git checkout -- ${file}` cannot revert them.  Interesting idea about `git config --global core.filemode false`!

Comment: This helped.  After checking out using 'git checkout -- file', try doing a git diff.  If it says the entire file has changed, but it really looks exactly the same, then it could be autocrlf.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comments, you must configure your repository to be case sensitive:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

This allows git to track both files (although the file system only shows one, which is enormously confusing). Here are replication steps to demonstrate what's happening, when git is correctly tracking case sensitivity:

```
git init /tmp/test && cd /tmp/test
git config core.ignorecase false
echo test>test && git add test && git commit -m "lowercase t"
mv test Test
```

Now `git status` shows no differences to `test`:

```
git status -s
 ?? Test
```

Commit `Test` and use `git ls-files` to see what we're now tracking:

```
git add Test && git commit -m "uppercase T"
git ls-files
 Test
 test
```

What does `ls` report? Why, just 'Test', naturally:

```
ls
 Test
```

Finally, what happens when we modify Test?

```
echo garbage>Test
git status -s
 M Test
 M test
```

What a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Use . instead of --

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: Why? `--` Is just a command to donate differences between commits and files. You'll get the exact same result using either. And I did.

Comment: `git checkout -- .` and `git checkout .` do the same thing, it's not going to either work better or worse. However, I discovered the reason why I'm experiencing this anomaly: OSX is case insensitive, there are files with the same names, but different cases. I'll post an answer the moment I come upon a solution. (core.ignorecase = true/false didn't work)

Comment: @HighwayofLife They apparently do not do the same thing. This has just worked for me, even though `--` didn't.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this same thing happened to me, but it was not a case-sensitivity problem.  Deleting the file, then changing branches resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What helped in my case: (also improving vinboxx's answer)

I had got configured `.gitattributes` in a following way:

```
* text eol=crlf
```

(I wanted -X renormalize to automatically use proper format after merge)

After temporarily commenting that line along with setting `git config core.autocrlf false`. Everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard all changes you've made, just use

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: That's what I did, see my question. Note that `git checkout -- .` and `git checkout .` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I found that the two problematic files had DOS line ending characters. I did this to fix the problem.

1- use a different clone to change the line ending to UNIX
2- blow away the clone where the problem was appearing and re clone it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem next time, I decided to convert my file system to case-sensitive.

I was pleasantly surprised that it is pretty easy on Mac OS (10.13.4).

It's possible to create quickly a new disk-volume with a different file system:

- run Disk Utility
- click on Container
- click on Volume (+)

I named new volume "Projects" and set Format to APFS (Case-sensitive).

After that I moved all projects to the new volume.

Answer (score -1):

I used git checkout -- .

Also git checkout .

== the same thing as the op said
both worked Mac OSX 10.7 and Linux, worked on both

with git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)
and
git 1.7.1 compiled

Try a different repo and see if you get the same results.
Maybe a command bug in the git version?

Comment: I discovered the problem. I'm working with a repo that appears to have multiple files with the same names and different cases. Since I'm on an OSX workstation, which is case-insensitive, the files appeared to change, but not really. That's why I can't reset them nor can I commit the "change". I have to actually rename the files on a case sensitive OS and commit the result.

Comment: Seems simple enough, but what a weird issue. (Good to know)

Answer (score -2):

when you delete file from filesystem using "rm -r file" you don't delete it from repository. Yo need do de same in git using "git rm "

Comment: I'm not trying to delete the files from the repository, I'm trying to reset them to the current status of the index. Please re-read the question. :)